# Linux Kernel Module Character Device Permissions

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Is it possible to create a character device in a linux kernel module that starts off mod 666?  Right now it's always 600 (owned by root), and I have to chmod it.  I could create udev entries to resolve it, but I'ld really rather the module do it automagically.

Is it possible? I can't find any information in the cdev_init or cdev_add documentation on this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do it by setting the `dev_uevent` method in the class structure. In this method you have to set the `DEVMODE` uevent variable. Here an example

```
static int my_dev_uevent(struct device *dev, struct kobj_uevent_env *env)
{
    add_uevent_var(env, "DEVMODE=%#o", 0440);
    return 0;
}

static struct class my_class = {
    .name                = "myname",
    .owner                = THIS_MODULE,
    .dev_uevent        = my_dev_uevent,
    [...]
};
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks! :)  Any advice where I can find stuff like this in the future?

Comment: Stuff about the kernel? Linux Device Driver 3rd edition, the Documentation directory in the kernel source code, and the best source of information: the  Linux kernel source itself ;)

Comment: This doesn't work with Linux version 3.19.8. `file_operations` has no `dev_uevent`.

Comment: `file_operations` probably never had `dev_uevent` method. If you read again the answer  you can see that I'm talking about `struct class` and you can easily verify that still today `dev_uevent` method is there

Comment: With a `printk` I found out this `my_dev_uevent` function is called 5 times for my driver..