# How to set the mode for a character device in a Linux kernel module?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module, device-driver

I'm creating a character device module that plays a game of Tic-tac-toe. I'm trying to program it so it sets it's `/dev/ticactoe` mode to `666`, instead of having a user use the `chmod` command.

My `main.c` contains the following with implementations of `tictactoe`'s `init` and `exit` (redacted for conciseness):

```
static dev_t device_number;
static struct cdev our_cdev;
static struct class* my_class = NULL;

static struct file_operations fops = {
.owner = THIS_MODULE,
.read = tictactoe_read,
.write = tictactoe_write,
.open = tictactoe_open,
.release = tictactoe_release,
};
```

I have a `tictactoe.h` containing the following:

```
#define MODULE_NAME "tictactoe"

int tictactoe_open(struct inode *pinode, struct file *pfile);
ssize_t tictactoe_read(struct file *pfile, char __user *buffer, size_t length, loff_t *offset);
ssize_t tictactoe_write(struct file *pfile, const char __user *buffer, size_t length, loff_t *offset);
int tictactoe_release(struct inode *pinode, struct file *pfile);
```

I read about `umode_t`, but I'm not sure how I might use that for this module. Can anyone lead me in the right direction or explain how to implement the `umode_t` variable? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Module for what? Is this a Linux module?

Comment: Yes, this is a Linux module.

Comment: Related also to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21767061/linux-kernel-module-character-device-permissions, almost a duplicate but with different approach in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The kernel source code for `/dev/{null,zero,...}` is a good place to look for this kind of stuff when you are in doubt, take a look at how this is implemented in [`drivers/char/mem.c`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/char/mem.c).

Once you've created the class `my_class` for your device, you should set the `->devnode` field to a function to set the mode you want. You can find modes in the `<linux/stat.h>` header, setting to `666` means `rw-rw-rw-`, which is `S_IRUGO|S_IWUGO`. It's a good idea to make this a constant somewhere in the code.

Here's the solution:

```
#define DEV_CLASS_MODE ((umode_t)(S_IRUGO|S_IWUGO))

static char *my_class_devnode(struct device *dev, umode_t *mode)
{
    if (mode != NULL)
        *mode = DEV_CLASS_MODE;
    return NULL;
}
```

Then in your module `init` function:

```
my_class = class_create(THIS_MODULE, "tictactoe");
if (IS_ERR(my_class)) {
    // Abort...
}

my_class->devnode = my_class_devnode;
```

---

Oh, and by the way, you do not need to `#define MODULE_NAME`, it's already defined automatically and it's `KBUILD_MODNAME`.