# creating device_create() with permission

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, file-permissions

Here is my code:

```
my_device = device_create(my_class, NULL, devno, NULL, "iot_device");
```

appears in */dev* folder

```
crw------- 1 root root (...) iot_device
```

I would like it to be created with a resolution of 666 (**crw-rw-rw-** )
I mean without using `chmod 666 iot_device`

Comment: This is what you want: [Linux Kernel Module Character Device Permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21767061/linux-kernel-module-character-device-permissions)

Comment: Another option is to use `device_class->devnode`, as done for example in `drivers/char/mem.c`: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/char/mem.c#L743

Comment: [Setting device permission from driver code fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47303639/setting-device-permission-from-driver-code-fails)  **great answer!!**

Answer (score 1):

You can create a file `/etc/udev/rules.d/my.rules` with content:

```
KERNEL=="iot_device", MODE="0666"
```

and refresh udev or reboot. There are many examples in `/usr/lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules` on my system.

Comment: The kernel can very well do that too. It would be silly if it had to rely on an userspace file to be edited.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli What would you propose? The kernel filters the mode settings when creating sysfs files. UDEV rules are more flexible because ownership and group ownership can be changed. I would recommend setting `MODE="0660"` and `GROUP="<somegroup>"` in the UDEV rules for most devices.

Comment: @IanAbbott well of course that makes sense, just saying that it's not the only option and kernel obviously still has control.

Comment: @IanAbbott My original answer had that it was not possible to do in kernel - I was wrong, hence the comment.